# Firebase Cloud Messaging for Flutter - Optionally handle background messages ERROR

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to add this field to my project but I got an error.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#optionally-handle-background-messages

I want to use firebase notifications in my application. I'm adding Aplication.java for this. After adding this file, the word registry is underlined in red.

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(**registry**);

ERROR:

```
\live_chat\android\app\src\main\java\com\**PACKAGENAME**\**APPNAME**\Application.java:18: error: incompatible types: PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
                                           ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**APPNAME**/android/app/src/main/java/app-organization-path/Application.java :

```
package **PACKAGENAME**;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are do this :

1 - Application.java class to your app in the **same directory** as your MainActivity.java.

2- name property of application(same your package) in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:name=".Application">
```

3- and for resloved FlutterFirebaseMessagingService i faced this problem before,  add last version of firebase-messaging in your android app build gradle file inside dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

then **sync android project** and try build flutter app

Comment: I'm adding Aplication.java for this. After adding this file, the word registry is underlined in red. GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);

Comment: app/build.grandle
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'

Comment: ok try to open android project(open application.java and click open for editing in android studio) and sync with gradle and run it

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/live-chat-831e0.appspot.com/o/Ek%20A%C3%A7%C4%B1klama%202020-01-31%20002558.png?alt=media&token=70dd93f5-2f9e-413c-91c6-ed174911553e

Comment: make sure you are import right GeneratedPluginRegistrant package, by remove all import and reimport auto

Comment: if not work try this line :    
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine));

Comment: RESULT : error: cannot find symbol
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine));
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable flutterEngine
  location: class Application
2 errors

Comment: sorry but i can't imagine why problem is still, try to show this issue and answer https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1467

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much! https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1467#issuecomment-562264234

Answer (score 2):

This is the code with the desired fix, also written in Kotlin.

```
package YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(
            registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin")
        );
    }

}
```